# How to improve solr's reading performance while big chunk of data gets loaded

Tags: solr, cloudera, solrcloud

We recently hit a problem on our production environment(40 CDH nodes running solr cloud), when there is no or small amount of data gets loaded to the solr cluster, the reading performance is quite decent. But when there is a bulk of data getting loaded to the cluster, during the loading period, the reading performance just gets dropped badly. Is there any solutions for this? e.g. split read/write. The bottom line is we can afford a certain level of slower writing, but definitely very good reading speed is wanted here.

Comment: What about tuning the autocommit params: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml?#Update_Handler_Section